# Does anyone know which country has the most bitcoins?

Tags: adoption, user-base

I was wondering if there is any stats out there that tell you how many bitcoins a country is holding. I want to make a presentation so i can persuade people to buy bitcoins, but i want to make sure they are really informed. Anything will help that is statistical related.

Comment: Can you define what you mean? Is this about governments or central banks posessing bitcoins? Or about their citizens? The best bet to find an answer could be geolocating the IP addresses seen relaying transactions, but I do not know if it even possible to distinguish between the originator and a relayer...

Comment: @pyramids the vast majority of Blockchain.info data says the middle of the ocean, ie unknown location 0N 0W

Comment: What is your definition of a bitcoin being held by country X? If there are 10 bitcoins on a 2-of-3 multisig address, and the three people holding the keys are in France, Italy and Spain, and the wallet is actually stored on a computer in England and a copy is in the cloud on a server hosted in Iceland.. What country holds the 10 bitcoins?

Answer (score 1):

Finding out which country has the most Bitcoin's is not something that you can easily calculate it is very difficult as it involves geolocating the IP addresses. But with the way they get transferred it could be very different the next day. Also a lot of Bitcoin users are concerned about privacy and security and it may be difficult to acquire the actual geolocation data.

On the other hand.I can give you the numbers for Top five countries for Bitcoin downloads as of Today
1.US (1,207,661)
2.China (505,904)
3.Germany (270,043)
4.UK (236,523)
5.Russia (226,680)

Hope this helps

Comment: any sources for these stats?

Comment: I got it from http://www.livemint.com/Industry/LI2IgSd3ugICUa7cxPvt3L/Bitcoins-gain-currency-in-India.html
Who's source is SourceForge.

Comment: there is no association of bitcoin addresses to IP. An IP address can get reported by running a bitcoin client, but that client doesn't report what addresses are in its wallet - to the network - nor does sending a transaction report that either.